# Visual studio 2015 community can't select target OS for Windows phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone

I just installed Visual studio 2015 community and when I select new project for Windows phone I can't select target version (as show on link) because my dropdown list is empty. Any suggestions on what could be wrong? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202937(v=vs.105).aspx

tnx

Comment: I have the same problem. I downloaded Visual Studio Community Edition but when I'm trying to create a Windows Phone 8 project I can't select anything in Target Windows Phone OS Version dropdown because it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Modify Visual Studio with select the "Windows 8.1 and Window Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools" option through Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Visual Studio 2015 -> Change -> Modify as below image. Then create a new project, the Target Windows Phone OS Version are list in the dropdown list.

Image: [Modify installation Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFbTm.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it will help you or not, but for me the solution was to just repair Visual Studio through Control Panel. Don't forget to choose features that are related to Windows Phone development in the installer.

For complete history I want to say that at first I installed Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7. Then I read that I won't be able to run emulator of Windows Phone on this OS. So I upgraded to Windows 10 but the problem did not disappear so easy. So finally I did what I had said earlier and that solved this problem for me.